# How do get unix sort to sort in same order as Java (by unicode value)

Tags: java, sort, unicode

I shell out sorting to the unix sort command in a Java program I've written.  However I am having problems arising from Java's string comparison behaving differently than the comparisons done by sort.

From the [Java Doc][1]:

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings.

From the sort man page:

> ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort
>          order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
>          byte values.

So my guess is need to sort with LC_ALL=C.  However I always thought this meant sort based on ASCII value, which means who knows what could happen with unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `LC_COLLATE` [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) category controls the sorting order. `LC_ALL` sets all categories.

With `LC_COLLATE=C`, strings are sorted byte by byte. The bytes don't have to be [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters (only byte values between 0 and 127 are ASCII). On a unix system, Unicode is almost always encoded as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). UTF-8 has the property that the encoding of characters as byte sequences preserves their ordering, and so sorting UTF-8 strings in byte lexicographic order is equivalent to sorting them in character lexicographic order. Therefore `LC_COLLATE=C` is suitable for sorting Unicode encoded in UTF-8 lexicographically according to the character values.

Note that Java does not actually sort according to the Unicode character values but according to their UTF-16 encoding. This makes a difference with [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), i.e. if you have code points above 65535.

Neither UTF-8 byte representation sorting nor Java sorting nor the `sort` utility in a UTF-8 locale on GNU/Linux take [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) into account, e.g. `á` (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT) is sorted differently from `á` (U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE) (in a UTF-8 locale, both end up equivalent to `a` in the first pass but the second pass sorts by code point).

Comment: This actually doesn't sort "in same order as Java" (because of surrogate pairs). Consider comparing U+FAD8 and U+1F574 - Java puts the second ("\ud83d\udd74") before the first ("\ufad8"), but UTF-8 byte comparison will correctly put them the other way around.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Oh, thank you. (The question did presuppose that Java order = Unicode value, I didn't realize that this was wrong but in retrospect I should have known since Java is from the UCS-2 era. My answer was for Unicode code points — which isn't the whole story either given the existence of combining characters.)